# Convert multiple EMF files to one

Tags: .net, printing

I would like to convert multiple emf files to one printable file. The idea is to be able to print multiple emf into one pdf using the virtual printer. 
Is there any windows standard(convert to spl and print) or free way?

Thank you!

edit: I figured out that I can do it in .net c# using the PrintDocument class. But still having problem how to set the correct page size and orientation according to the Metafile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally created the solution.

```
public class MetafilePrinter
{
    private Queue<Metafile> m_MetafileQueue = new Queue<Metafile>();
    private Metafile m_CurrentMetafile;
    private MetafileHeader m_CurrentMetafileHeader; 

    public bool PrintMetaFiles(IEnumerable<string> emfFiles, string printerName)
    {
        foreach (var emfFile in emfFiles)
        {
            m_MetafileQueue.Enqueue(new Metafile(emfFile));
        }

        var printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName; 
        printDocument.QueryPageSettings += printDocument_QueryPageSettings;
        printDocument.PrintPage += printDocument_PrintPage;
        printDocument.Print();

        return true; 
    }

    void printDocument_QueryPageSettings(object sender, QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
    {
        m_CurrentMetafile = m_MetafileQueue.Dequeue();
        m_CurrentMetafileHeader = m_CurrentMetafile.GetMetafileHeader();
        e.PageSettings.Landscape = m_CurrentMetafile.Width < m_CurrentMetafile.Height;
        e.PageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        int paperSizeWidht = (int)((m_CurrentMetafile.Width * 100) / m_CurrentMetafileHeader.DpiY); 
        int paperSizeHeight = (int)((m_CurrentMetafile.Height * 100) / m_CurrentMetafileHeader.DpiX);
        e.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize(string.Empty, paperSizeWidht, paperSizeHeight);
        e.PageSettings.PrinterResolution.X = (int)m_CurrentMetafileHeader.DpiX;
        e.PageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y = (int)m_CurrentMetafileHeader.DpiY; 
    }

    void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_CurrentMetafile, e.MarginBounds);
        e.HasMorePages = m_MetafileQueue.Count != 0;
    }
}
```